# How can I make night doors with command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a door that gets closed each night. I have all the blocks except the mechanism that will activate the "door command blocks" every night.

Comment: What do you mean by closed? Just shut, or locked down in some way? In terms of knowing when it's day/night, I'd use a light sensor. http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Daylight_Sensor

Comment: What do you mean by "door command blocks"?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming by "have all the blocks" you mean that you already have the command set up and just need to activate it at night. In that case you could use a daylight sensor and invert the signal so that the command is activated every night, and then another daylight sensor that isn't inverted that will activate at the start of the day.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

By "Night doors" I'm guessing you mean ones that open only at day/ night.

If you want it to open at night, then put a daylight sensor somewhere and invert the charge with a r/s torch and connect it to a cmd block that has a /setblock command or /fill command to open/ close a door ( you need two command blocks: one has the inverted charge and one doesn't. The inverted one will have /fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 air  the other will have /fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 )
switch the commands to make it day only